# Better way to get a parent element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

There is this button that when I try to click on, he kinda moves a little and opens a sub-menu. The solution is easy, just click on the div a few levels above him (still the button). But he is always changing class names.

I mannage to do it using this aberation `//div[@style]/span[@aria-label]/../../../../../..`.

I also tried to use `//div[@style]/span[@aria-label]/parent::div[@role="option"]`, but it did not work, and I don't know why.

Does anyone have any suggestions to make it more decent? I am sure that the "../" was not mean to be used on so many levels...

Also, I was trying to use CSS selectors for my entire project, but after spending some hours looking at StackOverflow answers, the solution seems to be use XPATH. If there is a way to do this operation with CSS Selectors, I would be very interested.

Comment: It seems you need "ancestor" axis. Something like `//div[@style]/span[@aria-label]/ancestor::div[@role="option"]`. But, to be sure, please post a sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't use your solution because the desired element has a class without value, so XPath became non-clickable (not sure why)...
Anyways, I appreciate your answer, but I guess I will need to stick with the crazy dots...

Comment: We can check if there's a better way to do this if you provide a part of the html code. Also, you can  use `//div[@style]/span[@aria-label]/ancestor::*[5]` to shorten your original expression.

Comment: @E.Wiest Yeah, that's way nice than what I was doing. Do you want to answer this so I can mark it as solved? Again, thanks. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten and make your XPath expression more readable with :

```
//div[@style]/span[@aria-label]/ancestor::*[5]
```

where `ancestor::*[5]` replaces `/../../../../../..`.